# simple foreach loop for debugging

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, foreach

Hi I am trying to write a simple `foreach` loop for debugging reasons so that when step into the code in visual studio I can see what value it holds.

The `Employee` model looks like this:

```
[Table("TblEmp")]
public class Employee
{
    [Key]
    public int EmployeeID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Gender { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
}
```

It doesn't have to do anything just that when I put the code in the controller it will be able to see what information is coming through.

I'm not good at debugging or loops so any help is greatly appreciated .The foreach is gonna be put in in the controller above this line.

```
Employee employee = employeeContext.Employees.Single(emp => emp.EmployeeID == id);
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: You're selecting a single entity; there is nothing to loop over. What _exactly_ is your goal and why do you think you need a loop for that? If you want to see what the `employee` variable holds, just place a breakpoint and inspect the variable.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something along the lines of:

```
var employees = employeeContext.Employees;

foreach (var employee in employees)
{
    Console.WriteLine("ID: {0}", employee.Id);
    Console.WriteLine("Name: {0}", employee.Name);
    Console.WriteLine("Gender: {0}", employee.Gender);
    Console.WriteLine("City: {0}", employee.City);
}
```

If you want to see each employee object in detail then simply put a breakpoint inside the loop and hover over the current `employee`. You could also use the Locals/Autos debug windows to inspect currently scoped objects.

Answer (score 0):

You need to iterate over all the employees?

Have you tried this?

```
foreach (Employee employee in employeeContext.Employees)
{
  .... do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach (Employee employee in employeeContext.Employees)
{
       var name=employee.Name; // Add debug point here
}
```

Comment: Additional explanation would improve your answer.